# Outlook Addin: DispEventAdvise exception

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, atl, outlook-addin

I want to creating an addin that captures when a {contact, calendar, task, note} is {created, edited, removed}. I have the following code, to make it shorter I removed all the code but the related to contact, since all types will be the same I guess.

AutoSync.h

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE AutoSync : 
 public wxPanel,
 public IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)>,
 public IDispEventSimpleImpl<2, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)>,
 public IDispEventSimpleImpl<3, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)>
{
public:
 AutoSync();
 ~AutoSync();

 void __stdcall OnItemAdd(IDispatch* Item); /* 0xf001 */
 void __stdcall OnItemChange(IDispatch* Item); /* 0xf002 */ 
 void __stdcall OnItemRemove(); /* 0xf003 */

 BEGIN_SINK_MAP(AutoSync)
  SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), 0xf001, OnItemAdd, &OnItemsAddInfo)
  SINK_ENTRY_INFO(2, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), 0xf002, OnItemChange, &OnItemsChangeInfo)
  SINK_ENTRY_INFO(3, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), 0xf003, OnItemRemove, &OnItemsRemoveInfo)
 END_SINK_MAP()

 typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)> ItemAddEvents;
 typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl<2, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)> ItemChangeEvents;
 typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl<3, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)> ItemRemoveEvents;

    private:

    CComPtr<Outlook::_Items> m_contacts;

    };
```

AutoSync.cpp

```
 _NameSpacePtr pMAPI = OutlookWorker::GetInstance()->GetNameSpacePtr();


MAPIFolderPtr pContactsFolder = NULL;
 HRESULT hr = NULL;

 //get folders
 if(pMAPI != NULL) {
  pMAPI->GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts, &pContactsFolder);
 }

 //get items
 if(pContactsFolder != NULL) pContactsFolder->get_Items(&m_contacts);

 //dispatch events
 if(m_contacts != NULL) {
    //HERE COMES THE EXCEPTION
  hr = ItemAddEvents::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_contacts,&__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents));
  hr = ItemChangeEvents::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_contacts,&__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents));
  hr = ItemRemoveEvents::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_contacts,&__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents));
 }
```

somewhere else defined:

```
extern _ATL_FUNC_INFO OnItemsAddInfo;
extern _ATL_FUNC_INFO OnItemsChangeInfo;
extern _ATL_FUNC_INFO OnItemsRemoveInfo;
_ATL_FUNC_INFO OnItemsAddInfo = {CC_STDCALL,VT_EMPTY,1,{VT_DISPATCH}};
_ATL_FUNC_INFO OnItemsChangeInfo = {CC_STDCALL,VT_EMPTY,1,{VT_DISPATCH}};
_ATL_FUNC_INFO OnItemsRemoveInfo = {CC_STDCALL,VT_EMPTY,0};
```

The problems comes in the

```
    hr = ItemAddEvents::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_contacts,&__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents));
  hr = ItemChangeEvents::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_contacts,&__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents));
  hr = ItemRemoveEvents::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_contacts,&__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents));
```

It gives exception in 'atlbase.inl' when executes method 'Advise':

```
ATLINLINE ATLAPI AtlAdvise(IUnknown* pUnkCP, IUnknown* pUnk, const IID& iid, LPDWORD pdw)
{
 if(pUnkCP == NULL)
  return E_INVALIDARG;

 CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer> pCPC;
 CComPtr<IConnectionPoint> pCP;
 HRESULT hRes = pUnkCP->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IConnectionPointContainer), (void**)&pCPC);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
  hRes = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(iid, &pCP);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    //HERE GIVES EXCEPTION
    //Unhandled exception at 0x2fe913e3 in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: 
    //Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.
  hRes = pCP->Advise(pUnk, pdw);
 return hRes;
}
```

I can't manage to understand why. Any sugestion here? Everything seems to be fine, but obviously is not. I've been stucked here for quite a long time. Need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first fact from a quick look is that you only need to derive from one `IDispEventSimpleImpl` per interface - you don't need one for every method in the interface:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE AutoSync : 
  public wxPanel,
  public IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)>
{
public:
  // ...
  BEGIN_SINK_MAP(AutoSync)
    SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), 0xf001, OnItemAdd, &OnItemsAddInfo)
    SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), 0xf002, OnItemChange, &OnItemsChangeInfo)
    SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), 0xf003, OnItemRemove, &OnItemsRemoveInfo)
  END_SINK_MAP()

  typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, AutoSync, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents)> ItemAddEvents;
  // ...
};
```

Try again with that simplification.

Comment: Simplification done, but still the very same exception. Any other idea?

Comment: @framara: Not really without digging out a test project later. A random shot in the dark would be to test with the `wxPanel` removed.

Comment: wxPanel removed and not working, still same exception. Thank you anyway, I really appreciate it ;)

Comment: I'm just giving random shots here. When debugging, 

-this
  -ATL::IDispEventSimpleImpl<...>
    -ATL::_IDispEventLocator<...>
      -ATL::_IDispEvent
         +__vfptr    0xcdcdcdcd
         +m_libid    {GUID_NULL}
         +m_iid      {GUID_NULL}
          m_wMayorVerNum    0x0000
          m_wMinorVerNum    0x0000
          m_dwEventCookie   0xfefefefe


Maybe it has nothing to do at all but, it looks a bit weird/bad to me no?

edit: I uploaded a pic since the formating of the comment is a bit complicated, http://yfrog.com/2sdebugj

Comment: Weird, but could be the debugger as well as some corruption. Can't really look into it before the weekend i think, sadly its no quick process to get a fresh test-project set up for Outlook Addins. There is also a [newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.office.developer.com.add_ins/) (but there wasn't much feedback for C++/ATL specifics *afair*) and maybe there is more activity in the MSDN social forums?

Comment: I've tried in both and there's no answer. The thing is that the code look pretty good (I think) so I can't get where that exception is coming from... This is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the reason was I was calling virtual methods from within the constructor. If your code in question is in the constructor, try moving it to FinalConstruct().

Answer (score 0):

I ever ran into this exception, removing ATL_NO_VTABLE can fix it.